# Getting Solr to index C files as text files

Tags: solr, solr4

I am currently working on a Solr installation that is going surprisingly well. The only real snag I haven't been able to figure out, is how to get it to index files with extensions outside of the norm. Specifically I have a bunch of C files that I should theoretically be able to index in the same manner as a text file. Are there any resources I'm missing that would explain how to make this possible.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: How exactly are you indexing the files? Which interface/approach?

Comment: have you tried feeding Solr with the c file ? Does it index it as text ? or throws an exception ?